Monitor fazing rainbow and then completely black, but Windows still detect it
My second monitor (Viewsonic 27" VX2718-PC-MHD) one day started fazing rainbow, turned white and then black with backlight monitor on, and it's still like that till this day.
The thing is, my PC still recognize it as when I open display setting. It tells me there are 2 monitor plugged in. When I use remote desktop software like AnyDesk, I can switch monitor and doing something on the Viewsonic side. Like the monitor it self displaying normally.
Anyone know what part that I need to swap? My guess may be it's the screen it self but asking to anyone more knowledgeable seems a better option.
Throwing it off seems kinda a waste, maybe there's still hope?
Oh yeah I also browsing lots of forum to see if someone have the same problem like me. It's just tad bit different than mine unfortunately, that's why I post.
Thanks in advance

you need to swap the monitor ... possible power supply failure ... possible bad internal connection

thanks for the info
